# Jquery Masked Input plugin not working within FancyBox(Lightbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using the jQuery **Masked Input Plugin** from here: [Digital Bush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

I'm also using the jQuery **FancyBox** plugin.

As far as I can tell, *they don't play nice together*.

---

My masked inputs do not work if in the FancyBox, though they work outside (same id #phone).  FancyBox displays fine.

The fancy box is on the page, **display: none** at page load....so I attempted to use the **callbackOnShow** setting, but id does not want to work.

---

**JAVASCRIPT**:*The alert function won't fire*

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   loadScroll();  
   $("a.inline").fancybox({  
       'callbackOnShow' : function(){alert('shown');}  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, **callbackOnShow** should be **onComplete**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   loadScroll();  
   $("a.inline").fancybox({  
       'onComplete' : function(){alert('shown');}  
   });  
})
```

---

Found here: [fanbcyBox/Blog](http://fancybox.net/blog)